# jQuery: find all appearances of item in table

Tags: jquery, arrays, loops, for-loop, find

I have a table that looks like the following.

Is there a way I can search through the table to find all occurances of a certain item (columns Cat) and then add the value from the next column (columns Vol) to an array like in the example below + show 0 if it does not appear in one column ?

Note: Each value can only appear once in a columns.

**My table:**

```
<table id="myTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="myHeader">Cat 1</th>
            <th>Vol 1</th>
            <th class="myHeader">Cat 2</th>
            <th>Vol 2</th>
            <th class="myHeader">Cat 3</th>
            <th>Vol 3</th>
            //...
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>item1</td><td>8</td><td>item2</td><td>7</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>item3</td><td>5</td><td>item2</td><td>7</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>item2</td><td>1</td><td>item1</td><td>5</td><td>item3</td><td>3</td>
        </tr>
        //...
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**Required outcome:**

```
var x = [8, 0, 5]  // example outcome when searching for "item1"
var y = [7, 7, 1]  // example outcome when searching for "item2"
var z = [0, 5, 3]  // example outcome when searching for "item3"
```

Many thanks for any help with this, Tim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like,

```
var searchTerm = "item1"
var result = $('#myTable td:contains(' + searchTerm + ')').map(function(){
                  return $(this).next('td').text(); 
             }).get();

console.log(result); //[8, 0, 5]
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tWBnn/)

Please read the following to know what's going on in the above code,

- [.map()](https://api.jquery.com/map/)
- [.next()](https://api.jquery.com/next/)
- [.text()](https://api.jquery.com/text/)
- [.get()](https://api.jquery.com/get/)

---

This is the way to write code in order to achieve your result : [Credits should goes to **Sphinx**]

```
var searchTerm = "item1";
var result = [];
$('#myTable tbody tr').each(function () {
    if ($(this).find('td:contains(' + searchTerm + ')').length === 0)
        result.push(0);
    else {
        result.push(+($(this).find('td:contains(' + searchTerm + ')').next('td').text()));
    }
});

alert(result); //[8, 0, 5]
```

### [Sphinx's DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sphnix/pGGR8/)

Comment: Thanks for this - looks great ! How can I adjust this to only search in TDs with a certain class ?

Comment: @user2571510 well, I just seen that requirement after posting this answer, we need to iterate each rows to build a result that you want.. if you want that for sure, just tell me, i'll write the code for you..

Comment: **How can I adjust this to only search in TDs with a certain class ?** Please use this selector to achieve that,`$('#myTable td.className:contains(' + searchTerm + ')')`

Comment: This is great - thanks a lot and sorry for changing it afterwards.

Comment: @user2571510 that doesn't matter, by the way glad to help..!

Comment: Thanks again. I just saw it doesn't return 0 if an item does not appear in a certain column.

Comment: @Rajaprabhu Aravindasamy Your way is great. But it doesn't return 0 if some items doesn't display on one row. So I figure out another way to do it based on your code. http://jsfiddle.net/sphnix/pGGR8/

Comment: @user2571510 sphinx had written the code that you are expecting, please see his demo in the previous comment..

Comment: @ Sphinx: This is exactly what I was missing - works great. Thanks a lot !